# Validation error when trying to run "rake db:seed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinerycms

My co-worker and I are using Rails 4.1.8. We are working on bare metal (no Docker, no VM). My cowerker was using Ruby 2.0.0 and I was using 2.1.5. We agreed to shift to the same version.

My co-worker began working on this without putting this into Github. He used scp to put it up on a server at Amazon. My co-worker installed the video plugin for RefineryCMS, and can run:

```
rake db:seed
```

I don't know if he's using `bundle exec` or relying on system gems.

I used scp to download the code from Amazon. I got all of those files that would normally be kept out by `.gitignore`. I installed the membership plugin, and if I run the command:

```
bundle exec rake db:seed
```

I get an error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Title can't be blank, Parts title can't be blank
```

and the stack trace points to:

```
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/extensions/videos/db/seeds.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

The full backtrace looks like this:

```
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:273:in `block in save!'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:329:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `block in transaction'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:209:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `transaction'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:273:in `save!'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/protected_attributes-1.0.8/lib/active_record/mass_assignment_security/validations.rb:17:in `create!'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/relation.rb:147:in `block in create!'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/relation.rb:292:in `scoping'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/relation.rb:147:in `create!'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/relation.rb:155:in `first_or_create!'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/extensions/videos/db/seeds.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/extensions/videos/db/seeds.rb:1:in `each'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/extensions/videos/db/seeds.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:543:in `load_seed'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/db/seeds.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:543:in `load_seed'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:200:in `load_seed'
/Users/cerhovice/projects/patton/royalbeauty/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:174:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

I opened that file, and inspected the values of `part` and `index`:

```
Refinery::Page.where(link_url: (url = "/videos")).first_or_create!(
  title: 'Videos',
  deletable: false,
  menu_match: "^#{url}(\/|\/.+?|)$"
) do |page|
  Refinery::Pages.default_parts.each_with_index do |part, index|
    [part, index] # => [Body, 0], then [Side Body, 1]
    page.parts.build title: part, body: nil, position: index
  end
end if defined?(Refinery::Page)
```

Despite what the stack trace says, it would make more sense if this error was happening in the plugin I just installed, so I opened:

```
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/refinerycms_membership-cd49cac06a43/db/seeds.rb
```

and I added some `put` statements. These never show in the terminal. Instead, I get the above output, and then `rake aborted!`.

It works for my co-worker, but not for me. How would a Rails programmer typically debug this kind of problem? How do I start to debug this? I am not asking for help with RefineryCMS.

From log/development.log:

```
 (0.1ms)  SELECT MAX("refinery_user_plugins"."position") AS max_id FROM "refinery_user_plugins"  WHERE "refinery_user_plugins"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 4]]

Refinery::UserPlugin Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "refinery_user_plugins".* FROM "refinery_user_plugins"  WHERE "refinery_user_plugins"."user_id" = ? AND "refinery_user_plugins"."name" = 'refinerycms-videos'  ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 4]]

Refinery::Page Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "refinery_pages".* FROM "refinery_pages"  WHERE "refinery_pages"."link_url" = '/videos'  ORDER BY "refinery_pages"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Refinery::Page: title, deletable, menu_match

WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Refinery::PagePart: title, body, position

WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Refinery::PagePart: title, body, position
(0.1ms)  begin transaction

Refinery::PagePart Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "refinery_page_parts"  WHERE ("refinery_page_parts"."title" IS NULL AND "refinery_page_parts"."refinery_page_id" IS NULL) LIMIT 1

Refinery::PagePart Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "refinery_page_parts"  WHERE ("refinery_page_parts"."title" IS NULL AND "refinery_page_parts"."refinery_page_id" IS NULL) LIMIT 1
 (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

Comment: In a separate terminal, you can `tail -f log/development.log` to see what is going on with the `rake db:seed`. It could be something as simple as unpermitted parameters.

Comment: If it were me, I'd google the mass-assign message, because that's clearly the problem:
 `WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Refinery::Page: title, deletable, menu_match

WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Refinery::PagePart: title, body, position

WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Refinery::PagePart: title, body, position
(0.1ms)  begin transaction`

Comment: Note: asking why you received a downvote is a good idea... complaining that all active S/O people downvote is less of a good idea... ;)

Comment: (You've commented in your question that a moderator removed a relevant bit of information - from what I can see they just moved it, so it appears after your backtrace. Also, anyone without a diamond after their name is not a moderator - they're just a community member like you. As you gain reputation points, you can edit and improve other people's posts).

Comment: Is this question still relevant after close to six months? Are you using the `protected_attributes` gem?